# Let $X_n$ a sequence such that $x_n \leq 7$ and $x_n < x_{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X_n$ a sequence such that $x_n \leq 7$ and $x_n < x_{n+1}$ show that $x_n$ converges without using Theorem of the Convergence of Monotonic Sequences

the problem is I don't understand how the sequence is defined, any hint of what should I do to prove it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I don't understand how the sequence is defined"? The point of the question is that there is no specific sequence; our goal is to show that this holds for **any** sequence with these properties.

Comment: Also, have you learned the formal definition for the convergence of a sequence (i.e. the definition with $\epsilon > 0$)? My best guess is that the asker expects a proof of convergence that uses this definition.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, we use the formal definition $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq m$ then $|x_n - x|< \epsilon$

Comment: Has your class discussed the "supremum" (least upper bound) of a set?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes supremum and infimum

Comment: @BenGrossmann $x_n$ is an increasing sequence but $x_n \leq 7$ then converges to 7?

Comment: Not necessarily

Comment: For example, consider the sequence
$$
x_n = 2 - \frac 1{n+1}.
$$
This sequence is increasing, and it is true that $x_n\leq 7$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof can be written with the following outline. The questions in parentheses are questions that should be answered in order to make the proof complete.

---

Let $S = \{x_n : n \in \Bbb N\}$, and let $\alpha$ denote the supremum $\alpha = \sup(S)$ (why does the supremum exist/why is it finite?) We will show that $x_n$ converges to $\alpha$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Take $m \in \Bbb N$ to be such that $x_m > \alpha - \epsilon$ (how do we know that such an $m$ exists?). For any $n \geq m$, we see that $|x_n - \alpha| \leq |x_m - \alpha| < \epsilon$ (how?). Thus, $x_n$ converges to $\alpha$.

Comment: the supremum exists because S is bounded and by supremum theorem, and m exists because is a increasing sequence?

Comment: @Gustavo Your first answer is correct. Your second answer is not correct.